# How to add javascript code to make a custom popup display?

Tags: javascript, class, hyperlink, popup

What I've created is a custom popup with CSS, this is not an actual Windows popup. This custom popup can only be open or display in its web page. Unfortunately, I cannot find the right javascript code to make the popup open. Can anyone be glad to help me with this problem please?

HTML Code Description: This is the class for the popup to open/display...

> class="popup popup-manager"

HTML Code Link Description: This is the link I'd like the people to be able to click on in order to make the popup display...

> a href="#">Become a member

I'm a beginner with javascript, so if you can please provide me the full code...

Answer (score 0):

You can show and hide your window with javascript. If you are using jQuery:

```
$('.popup').show();
$('.popup').hide();
```

To make it work with your link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="showPopup();">Become a member</a>
```

and you can have a JS function as:

```
function showPopup(){
    $('.popup').show();
}
```